# Unable to load xml file with jquery in phonegap project from assets path

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have huge problem with loading `xml` file from `assets` path by `jQuery` mobile in phonegap project.

I need to load an `xml` file. File is placed in the **root** of my project. Problem is with ajax url: **"language.xml"**. Here is my code:

```
var language = 'english';
var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;
$.ajax({
    url: "language.xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            if(text.match(regEx)){
              $("." + id).replaceWith('<a href="mailto:'+text+'" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" rel="external" data-mini="true">'+text+'</a>');
            }
            else{
              $("." + id).html(text);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I use the absolute path, I am able to load this file adding url: `file:///android_asset/www/language.xml`

This is good only for Android assets. But I need the correct path for **iOS** too.

#### Is it possible to link URL path absolutly/relativly by jQuery to be able to load file in Android/iOS devices?

**UPDATE**
Code above is correct. Fail was in testing within the desktop browser. Project works fine on Android and iOS with relative paths.

There's **no need** to add absolute path like `file:///android_asset/www/` for Android or `file:///var/mobile/Applications/7D6D107B-D9DC-479B-9E22-4847F0CA0C40/YourApplication.app/www/` for iOS .

Comment: Is you HTML file in the folder `www`? If yes, did you try using `url: "./language.xml"` (additional `./`) instead of `url: "language.xml"` ?

Comment: @Petr Latal, consider posting answer to your own question, if you has found a solution

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY:

```
    $("#inputString").live("keyup", function(e) 
    {
       $.post("FILE.PHP",{ char:$("#inputString").val() },
         function(data){},'json');
    });
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `list` WHERE `name` LIKE '%{$_POST['queryString']}%'";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);
        if($result) 
        {
        foreach ($result as $value) echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$value['name'].'\');">'.$value['name'].'</li>';
        } 
}
?>
```

CSS:

```
#autoSuggestionsList {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 30px 4px;
    width: 175px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #c3d9ff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3d9ff 0%, #b1c8ef 41%, #98b0d9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c3d9ff), color-stop(41%,#b1c8ef), color-stop(100%,#98b0d9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3d9ff 0%,#b1c8ef 41%,#98b0d9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c3d9ff 0%,#b1c8ef 41%,#98b0d9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c3d9ff 0%,#b1c8ef 41%,#98b0d9 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3d9ff 0%,#b1c8ef 41%,#98b0d9 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3d9ff', endColorstr='#98b0d9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.suggestionList {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.suggestionList li {
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.suggestionList li:hover {
    background-color: #659CD8;
    color: #fff;
}
#autoSuggestionsList li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    behavior: url('./css/PIE.htc');
}
#autoSuggestionsList li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url('./css/PIE.htc');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your xml file in "www" folder and then you should be possible to access the file with just the filename.

Also, see the autocomplete example : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#xml
In the demo they have directly accessed "london.xml"

```
$.ajax({
  url: "london.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function( xmlResponse ) {
  var data = $( "geoname", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
  //alert($('name', this).text());
  return {
    value: $( "name", this ).text() + ", " +
            ( $.trim( $( "countryName", this ).text() ) || "(unknown country)" ),
    id: $( "geonameId", this ).text()
  };
 });
```

Hopefully it will work.